# How to call php file on checkout page in shopify using custom app

Tags: shopify, shopify-activemerchant

I am creating shopify app and there i gave option for video url or iframe in backend and now i want to access it on checkout thank you page.

Reference url of checkout page: 
https://checkout.shopify.com/13865223/checkouts/8a6f73e477342f511954f161a2707135/thank_you

Comment: We need more info

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to place content on the order status page (also known as the thank you page) then try [creating a ScriptTag](https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/scripttag) with the `scope` property set to `order_status`.

You can add content boxes to the page using the [`Shopify.Checkout.OrderStatus.addContentBox()` JavaScript API.](https://help.shopify.com/themes/customization/order-status/order-status-javascript-asset)

Comment: Is it possible to add content box from api?

Comment: Because i am creating app and i want to add iframe from api to order status page.

Comment: You have to follow the rules. You cannot do whatever you want. Use a ScriptTag, and if you're clever, you can introduce your App to checkout.